# Count previous occurences of a string across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have a four column matrix with a chronological index, and three columns of names (strings). Here is some toy data:

```
x = rbind(c(1,"sam","harry","joe"), c(2,"joe","sam","jack"),c(3,"jack","joe","jill"),c(4,"harry","jill","joe"))
```

I want to create three additional vectors that count (for each row) any previous (but not subsequent) occurrences of the name. Here would be the desired result for the toy data:

```
y = rbind(c(0,0,0),c(1,1,0),c(1,2,0),c(1,1,3))
```

I am at a loss of how to approach the problem, and have searched Stack Overflow for relevant examples. dplyr provides answers for finding total counts, but (as far as I can tell) not on a row by row basis.

I attempted to write a function to deal with this problem in a single-column space, but with no luck, i.e.

```
thing = sapply(x,function(i)length(grep(i,x[x[1:i]])))
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using matrices, or is your actual data read in as `data.frame`s?

Comment: Seems pretty clear from you desired output that this is not being done "for each row", but rather being done by traversal of the entire matrix "by row." The natural ordering of R matrices is by column which is why @AnandaMahto needed to use transpose operations twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical `ave` + `seq_along` type of problem, but we need to convert the data to vectors first:

```
t(`dim<-`(ave(rep(1, prod(dim(x[, -1]))), 
              c(t(x[, -1])), FUN = seq_along)  - 1, 
          rev(dim(x[, -1]))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    1    0
# [3,]    1    2    0
# [4,]    1    1    3
```

---

Perhaps more readable:

```
## x without the first column as a vector
x_vec <- c(t(x[, -1]))

## The values that you are looking to obtain...
y_vals <- ave(rep(1, length(x_vec)), x_vec, FUN = seq_along) - 1

## ... in the format you want to obtain them
matrix(y_vals, ncol = ncol(x) - 1, byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    1    1    0
# [3,]    1    2    0
# [4,]    1    1    3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
el = unique(c(x[,-1]))
val = Reduce(`+`, lapply(el, function(u) {b=c(t(x[,-1]))==u; b[b==T]=(cumsum(b[b==1])-1); b}))

matrix(val, ncol=ncol(x[,-1]), byrow=T)
#         [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    0
#[3,]    1    2    0
#[4,]    1    1    3
```